# Are large $p$ and $q$ values for ARMA models bad?

Tags: time-series, arima

I've been learning about ARMA models in my time series course and noticed that for most ARMA($p,q$) models, $p$ and $q$ never really get larger than 3 or so. Is there a reason why models don't normally have larger values?

Thanks!